# How to calculate the digest / Which algorithm will be used?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I've found an C++ API there was called from Java JNI. The `libcma.so` contains the method `Java_com_smule_android_network_core_NetworkUtils_makeDigest` which will create an Digest - I Think it's `MD5`.

Here is the reversed source:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Bizarrus/Sing/master/cma.cpp

And here is the `JNI` definition:

https://github.com/Bizarrus/Sing/blob/7ef0e748bae710bde2d07111bd66f1e7fc0810b4/com/smule/android/network/core/NetworkUtils.java#L53

Can anyone tell me, which `Algorithm` will be used?

**Edit**

Following `HTTP-Request` will be made:

```
POST http://api-sing.smule.com/v2/login/guest?msgId=1776&appVersion=5.7.5&app=sing_google&appVariant=1&digest=179645edb702ce4a57197141522d848145f8861f HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: com.smule.singandroid/5.7.5 (6.0,F3311,de_DE)
Content-Type:   application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 501
Host:   api-sing.smule.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding:    gzip

{
    "common": {
        "advId": "e133b6d9-25b1-4651-b4b8-94d80fa25ed9",
        "automaticLogin": true,
        "device": {
            "carrierCountry": "de",
            "country": "DE",
            "deviceId": "a:e133b6d9-25b1-4651-b4b8-94d80fa25ed9",
            "deviceType": "AND",
            "googlePlayServices": "12.6.85 (040306-197041431)",
            "hasMail": true,
            "lang": "de",
            "limitAdTrack": false,
            "locale": "de_DE",
            "machine": "F3311",
            "manufacturer": "Sony",
            "os": "6.0",
            "product": "F3311",
            "screenSize": "normal",
            "script": ""
        },
        "pulp": 17,
        "tzOffset": 3600,
        "vorgom": true
    },
    "forceNewPlayer": true,
    "lookupAccount": true
}
```

with following `Response`:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.11.5
Date:   Sun, 24 Jun 2018 16:27:31 GMT
Content-Type:   application/json; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding:  chunked
X-Smule-Host:   a155.sf.smle.co
X-Smule-Digest: 64dc15893bbf43240798c73ae652bfb80e848f57
Set-Cookie: L=N; Max-Age=172800; Expires=Tue, 26 Jun 2018 16:27:31 GMT; Path=/; Domain=.smule.com; Secure
Cache-Control:  no-cache
Content-Encoding:   gzip

{
    "data": {
        "loginResult": {
            "elControl": {
                "npt": false
            },
            "handleNew": false,
            "handlePrefill": true,
            "language": "de",
            "loginCount": 1,
            "playerId": 1762444898,
            "playerNew": true,
            "playerNewlyRegistered": false,
            "playerStat": {
                "installDate": 1529857651000
            },
            "policyUrl": "https://www.smule.com/privacy/embed/20180523",
            "policyVersion": "PRIVACY_POLICY_20180523",
            "serverTime": 1529857651,
            "sessionToken": "g4_10_wma5HOX13kDeho2gvEuIQyf5EnUaAp0Uw3C24O5w9s9xUB1U0JOC0w==",
            "sessionTtl": 86400,
            "showEmailOpt": true,
            "termUrl": "https://www.smule.com/termsofservice/embed/20180523"
        },
        "settings": {}
    },
    "status": {
        "code": 0,
        "message": "ok",
        "version": 1
    }
}
```

On the `POST` request, the `Query-Argument` **digest`is the`Hash`of the request. These`Digest`will be created by`Java_com_smule_android_network_core_NetworkUtils_makeDigest`(i think). I don't know, which data will be used for the`Hashing-Algorithm`- I've tried to reproduce the`Digest` with following parameters:

- Only all `Query-Parameters`, sorted alphabetically, exclude the `digest`-Argument (These method will be used on the Website under JavaScript`
- Only the Content-Body, in JSON-String (tried as pretty-printed and comprimized)
- Content-Body **and** Query-Parameters expected as above

I've tried some combinations of data to reproduce the `digest`, but i've found no solutions, which data reprensent the original digest.

From the `Response` on the `X-Smule-Digest` header will be hashed by `MD5`, that i had reproducted last week. Here (in  `PHP`) a working sample to calculate the `X-Smule-Digest`:

```
$string  = sprintf('%s=%s', 'secret', 'M=|ZUyMu^-qWb}VL^jJd}Mv)8y%bQWXf>IFBDcJ>%4zg2Ci|telj`dVZ@');
$string .= sprintf('&%s=%s', 'path', '/user/json/login'); // sample url-path
$string .= sprintf('&%s=%s', 'csrf', $this->csrf); // from Website, <meta content="([^"]+)" name="csrf-token" or from Header "x-csrf-token"
$string .= sprintf('&%s', http_build_query($this->data)); // POST-Body

$array = explode('&', $string);
sort($array); // Alphabetical sort
$x_smule_digest = md5(implode('&', $array));
```

Comment: How about you feed it a sample of known data and you compare the output to that of well-known hashs ?

Comment: I will update the question with tried examples, thanks for the information :)

Comment: The question was updated! :)

Comment: I think it’s some kind of sha1

Answer (score 1):

1 . The digest you indicate is 40 characters long, and contains numbers from `0` to `9` and letters from `a` to `f`. So it is 40 hex values. So it is most probably created using `SHA-1` digest function.

2 . The C++ function you indicate has the following signature :

```
int32_t Java_com_smule_android_network_core_NetworkUtils_makeDigest(int32_t * a1, int32_t a2, int32_t a3)
```

And the corresponding signature in the Java source code is :

```
private static native String makeDigest(String str, byte[] bArr);
```

The first argument `a1` may be a pointer reserved by the JNI environment. So, input `a1` input set aside, the function takes two arguments : a string and an array of byte, and return one string : the digest. The C++ code itself is too complex for me to dig in.

3 . This JNI function is used twice in the Java file you indicate. In functions `m18107a` and `m18106a`. Let's add some comments to the source code :

```
// Function that takes three arguments :
//      - a list of pairs of string we will call the "json pairs"
//      - a string we will call the "secret"
//      - an other string we will call the "optional token"
// and return the returned string of makeDigest which may be the digest.
public static String m18107a(List<Pair<String, String>> list, String str, String str2)
{
    // Sort the json pairs alphabetically according to the first string of each pairs.
    // (Check the source code of C35442 to verify my statement, I may be wrong )
    Collections.sort(list, new C35442());

    // Create a single string, that concatenate all the json pairs.
    // ( I guess { age : 21, name : "bob" } becomes "age21namebob" )
    // We will call that the "digest input"
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (Pair pair : list) {
        stringBuilder.append((String) pair.first).append((String) pair.second);
    }

    // Append the "digest input" just created with the "optional token" if it exists.
    if (str2 != null) {
        stringBuilder.append(str2);
    }

    // Send the "secret" string, and the "digest input" as BYTES (may be important)
    // Return the digest computed as returned string of the function.
    return makeDigest(str, stringBuilder.toString().getBytes());
}


// Function that takes four arguments :
//      - a string str
//      - a number j
//      - a string str2
//      - a string str3 (can be null, as seen later)
// and return the returned string of makeDigest which may be the digest.
public static String m18106a(String str, long j, String str2, String str3)
{
    // Create a single string, that concatenate j and str2.
    // We will call that the "digest input"
    StringBuilder append = new StringBuilder().append("").append(j).append(str2);

    // If str3 is null, make it empty.
    if (str3 == null) {
        str3 = "";
    }

    // Send the "secret" string, and the "digest input" concatenated with str3, as BYTES (may be important).
    // Return the digest computed as returned string of the function.
    return makeDigest(str, append.append(str3).toString().getBytes());
}
```

It will be hard to go further. Try to dig few things :

- Where are these functions `m18107a` and `m18106a` called ? Can you at least find what are the inputs of these ? So you can play with the good inputs.
- Can you put breakpoints around these functions ? To track inputs and outputs and try to reproduce ?
- From all the suspected inputs, can you find a way to modify only one per one and check if the digest changes ? To eliminate suspected inputs.